# При импорте дампа вылетает ошибка: dumpfile: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "gis_hotels_pkey"

Tags: linux, postgresql, база-данных

Подскажите с такой бедой. Есть дамп postgresql. При его импорте в базу вижу

```
psql:dumpfile: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "gis_hotels_pkey"
```

Когда то борол такое уже, но подзабыл, там заменять нужно при импорте кажетсья. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Комманда импорта выглядит так

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d mybase -f dumpfile
```

Comment: [этот ответ](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81188/72680) (и ссылки в нём) может оказаться полезным.

Comment: Мне не подходит. Лучше уже очистить базу и внести дамп в пустую. Разве нет опции REPLACE? при импорте?

Comment: вероятно, мы видим разное (что вполне возможно, т.к. я «не силён» в *postgresql*): я вижу предложение импортировать сначала *схему*, а затем *данные*, в промежутке внеся в импортированную схему необходимые изменения. // пересмотрел то, что по ссылке, не увидел упоминания программы [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html), которая позволяет делать такое выборочное восстановление (схема отдельно от данных) из уже готового *dump*-а.

Comment: еще один момент. Проверте не ту ли у вас триггеров которые генерируют ID строки даже если она не null. в этом случае вам придется sequence (последовательность)  создавать со значением 0 вместо текушего из основной базы

Comment: pg_restore не подходит. база слита в другом формате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо ваша бд mybase не пустая. При заливке дампа встречаются дублирующие данные, а поле gis_hotel_pkey должно быть уникальным. Можно попробовать очистить все данные с mybase, а потом пытаться залить базу. Либо, если данные в mybase необходимо сохранить, то попытаться дропнуть unique constraint "gis_hotels_pkey", затем запросом найти дублирующие записи - оставить нужные и восстановить constraint.

Comment: так и есть база не пустая. как можно очистить?

Comment: Самый простой способ - создать дамп бд, где только схема, потом дропнуть бд и накатить схему. 
`pg_dump --schema-only mybase > schema.dump`
`dropdb mybase`
`psql -f schema.dump mybase`

Comment: самый легкий способ в моей ситуации был, удалить базу и создать новую пустую, и сделать в неё импорт коммандой описаной в вопросе.